# Functional Programming printing numbers divisible by 2

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I am trying to learn functional programming and I am writing a function that prints numbers divisible 2. I know that in functioning programming it should avoid loops and should have referential transparency, so variables should be immutable. This is the function I wrote, does this fit the functional programming paradigm?

```
public static void evenNumbers(int start, int end)
{

    if (start <= 20)
    {
        if (start % 2 == 0)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(start);
        }
        evenNumbers(start + 1, end);
    }
}
```

Edit I made some changes to the code

```
public static void evenNumbers(int start, int end)
    {

        if (start <= 20)
        {
            if (start % 2 == 0)
            {
                return start;
            }
            evenNumbers(start + 1, end);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're trying to learn functional programming, then why not use a functional langauge, like F#?

Comment: How is `question1` defined? A functional approach would be to return a sequence of matching numbers rather than executing side-effects (like `Console.WriteLine`) as part of the process.

Comment: I believe calling Console.WriteLine inside already breaks the functional nature of this function.

Comment: To fit FP your function should return list, and not print it.

Comment: If I change System.Console.WriteLine(start) to return start would the be functional?

Comment: You should get something like this:   Integer.Range(1,20).Where(n => n.IsEven).PrintSomething()

Answer (score 3):

If you want write "functional" code in c# - use LINQ extension methods

```
var valuesToPrint = 
    Enumerable.Range(start, end - start)
              .Where(value => number % 2 == 0)
              .Select(value => value.ToString());
var output = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, valuesToPrint)

// Console is external resource (aka global state)
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

If you big fan of LINQ you can build output with `.Aggregate` extension method

```
var output = 
    Enumerable.Range(start, end - start)
              .Where(value => number % 2 == 0)
              .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                         (builder, value) => builder.AppendLine(value),
                         builder => builder.ToString());

Console.Write(output);
```

Some would argue about `Aggregate` with `StringBuilder` not being pure functional, because we update internal state of same instance of `StringBuilder`.

Comment: if the list is not huge, we could consider replacing the String.Join with `.Aggregate((a, x) => a + ", " + x)`

Comment: @Matt.G, I would suggest to use `Aggregate` with `StringBuilder`, then this approach will work for bigger size collections too.